# Linking taking over hour and half- how can I reduce linker time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I have a C++11 Visual Studio 2012 project which creates a number of items upon start-up, for use to handle objects arriving during real-time. Originally I had 600 items created but I increased this to 6000. As a consequence the linker time has increased (probably linearly).

I have this code duplicated 6000 times (one for each object):

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> x1 = boost::make_shared<MyClass>("a", b, c);
x1->addSomething(an_object_shared_across_all_6000);
another_object_shared_across_all_6000->addObject(x1);
an_unordered_map[x1->getSomething()] = x1;

// x2 etc
// x3 etc
// .
// .
```

As I was compiling using MSVC 2012 I had to create six functions, each creating 1000 of the above objects (because MSVC throws a compiler error saying I had reached a maximum for something).

I have set my Release mode linking to be incremental.

Is there anything else I can do to significantly speed-up the linking process? By this I mean when the build window says "code generation".

I do have access to VS2013- not sure if that is supposed to be quicker??

**UPDATE**- The above project was stored on a velociraptor hard drive. I have just moved the project to an SSD, re-ran and linking took 9 mins. Does this make sense??

Comment: +1. I've been sitting here for 10 minutes trying to find something to say and I got nothing. You win!

Comment: Why not create the 6000 objects on the heap during process startup?

Comment: Funny, I clicked on this question intending to say "SSD!". The linking process is very sensitive to seek times, which SSDs hardly suffer from at all.